# Remove Improperly Nested Spans from MS Excel Generated HTML Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is some mostly cleaned HTML output from Microsoft Excel, but there are a bunch of improperly nested `<span>` elements in there. What would be the best way to remove these elements using Javascript (ideally without relying on jQuery)?

I am already doing a lot of cleaning to get to this point, but removing the `<span>` elements is proving to be a challenge. Thanks for any advice you can offer!

```
<table>
   <tbody data-key="10020">
      <tr data-key="10009">
         <span data-key="10002"><span data-offset-key="10002-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10004" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10003"><span data-offset-key="10003-0">Done</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10005"><span data-offset-key="10005-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10007" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10006"><span data-offset-key="10006-0">Yes</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10008"><span data-offset-key="10008-0">
         </span></span>
      </tr>
      <tr data-key="10018">
         <span data-key="10011"><span data-offset-key="10011-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10013" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10012"><span data-offset-key="10012-0">Done</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10014"><span data-offset-key="10014-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10016" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10015"><span data-offset-key="10015-0">Yes</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10017"><span data-offset-key="10017-0">
         </span></span>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all `span` elements? Or just specific ones?

Comment: I don't want to remove span elements that have content in them, but I do want to remove the empty ones that are located outside of the `td` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I know you prefer a solution without relying on jQuery, But, This is here, as the fallback solution, if no one offers using pure javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr > span').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tbody data-key="10020">
      <tr data-key="10009">
         <span data-key="10002"><span data-offset-key="10002-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10004" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10003"><span data-offset-key="10003-0">Done</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10005"><span data-offset-key="10005-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10007" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10006"><span data-offset-key="10006-0">Yes</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10008"><span data-offset-key="10008-0">
         </span></span>
      </tr>
      <tr data-key="10018">
         <span data-key="10011"><span data-offset-key="10011-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10013" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10012"><span data-offset-key="10012-0">Done</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10014"><span data-offset-key="10014-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10016" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10015"><span data-offset-key="10015-0">Yes</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10017"><span data-offset-key="10017-0">
         </span></span>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's funny, I actually just decided the same minute you posted this to do something very similar. I am just going to use that same CSS: `tr > span` to set those improper elements to `display: none`

Thanks very much for your reply!

Comment: @Slapbox You're welcome Dude. I appreciate your openness & flexibility. It seems you've offered a better fallback( The-Last-Man-Standing! ;-) ) solution, if no proper js candidate shows up. Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

Assuming are you talking about client side JS running in a browser that has parsed the invalid HTML … you can't. The browser will have already performed error recovery at that point.

[image: Screenshot of DOM Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

With pure ES5 javascript you can remove those elements, after browser rendering, with code below. It needs to be reverse because the returned HTMLCollection object have all elements in order they appear on the document, and it auto update itself to synchronize with the DOM tree. Some reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName).

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span')

for (var i = spans.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var elm = spans[i]
  var parent = elm.parentNode
  var txt = elm.innerText

  parent.removeChild(elm)

  if (txt) {
    parent.innerText = txt 
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tbody data-key="10020">
      <tr data-key="10009">
         <span data-key="10002"><span data-offset-key="10002-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10004" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10003"><span data-offset-key="10003-0">Done</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10005"><span data-offset-key="10005-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10007" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10006"><span data-offset-key="10006-0">Yes</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10008"><span data-offset-key="10008-0">
         </span></span>
      </tr>
      <tr data-key="10018">
         <span data-key="10011"><span data-offset-key="10011-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10013" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10012"><span data-offset-key="10012-0">Done</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10014"><span data-offset-key="10014-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10016" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10015"><span data-offset-key="10015-0">Yes</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10017"><span data-offset-key="10017-0">
         </span></span>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

With ES6 you can do as below. Problems described before doesn't apply.

```js
var spans = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span'))

spans.forEach(function (elm) {
  var txt = elm.innerText
  
  if (txt) {
    elm.parentNode.innerText = txt
  }
  
  elm.remove()
})
```

```html
<table>
   <tbody data-key="10020">
      <tr data-key="10009">
         <span data-key="10002"><span data-offset-key="10002-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10004" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10003"><span data-offset-key="10003-0">Done</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10005"><span data-offset-key="10005-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10007" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10006"><span data-offset-key="10006-0">Yes</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10008"><span data-offset-key="10008-0">
         </span></span>
      </tr>
      <tr data-key="10018">
         <span data-key="10011"><span data-offset-key="10011-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10013" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10012"><span data-offset-key="10012-0">Done</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10014"><span data-offset-key="10014-0">
         </span></span>
         <td data-key="10016" style="text-align: left;"><span data-key="10015"><span data-offset-key="10015-0">Yes</span></span></td>
         <span data-key="10017"><span data-offset-key="10017-0">
         </span></span>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```